# Analytical calculation vs FEA

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, finite-element-method, aerospace-engineering, solid-mechanics

In terms of calculated stress, strain, displacement etc which method yields more conservative results. Analytical calculation or numeric calculation?

Comment: What do you mean by "conservative" ?

Comment: I mean more safe side

Comment: It completely depends on the assumptions that you make in both cases. There is no "correct" answer to this question. If you provide a specific example of the situation you're worried about, and the hand calcs you're planning, vs the constraints etc. you'd put into FEA, then we might be able to help. In the meantime I'm voting to close as too broad.

Comment: How do you do an "analytical calculation" without using any numbers?

Comment: Numeric calculation means FEA @alephzero

Comment: "More conservative" does not mean "better" or "useful". A "more conservative" design for a crash proof car would say "make the bodywork out of 6 inch thick armour plate, and limit the top speed to 5mph". Safe, yes. Useful, no.

Comment: @dancineer There are lots of numeric calculations done by engineers that don't use FEA. But I asked you how you propose to do an *analytical calculation* without using numbers.

Comment: @alephzero There is a difference between numerical and analytical methods. Analytical approaches typically involve solving “by hand”, and the solutions obtained are exact (in theory). When closed-form solutions do not exist, numerical methods are employed, where the solution is subject to numerical errors. Compare solving a linear ODE by exact solution, getting a general solution, vs solving by numerical integration. I believe this is what the author meant by analytical and numeric calculation.